# Issues importing CSS file into React Component without Ejecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

[image]

From understanding, based on the latest create-react-app version, I don't actually have to "npm run eject" my application. In fact, previously when I did so, I couldn't find the relevant webpack.js..etc to modify.

[image]
Could someone advise how can I still import CSS files into my react component without having to eject my application?

Thank you in advance! (:

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you just have to do `import 'path/to/stylefilename.css'`.

For example if the the component and your css file are in the same folder just do `import './index.css'`

Comment: What do you mean by 'path/to'? If you're referring to normal path directory, this doesn't work. 

My CSS files are in the same folder as my respective components. I tried import './index.css' as well, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One can simply resolve this by

1. Adding .module before .css of all of their CSS files so long as the CSS file and JS file are in the folder/directory.
2. Adding .module within the import statement as well  `import classes from "./BuildControls.module.css";`